# Bootstrap tweeter. Как скрыть предыдущий popover на странице при нажатии другого?

Tags: всплывающее-окно, bootstrap, javascript

**Здравствуйте!**

Для примера есть страница (**код ниже**), на ней расположены кнопки с popover от **bootstrap tweeter**.

При нажатии появляется желаемое окошко, с этим всё в порядке.

Но если далее нажать следующую кнопку появиться ещё одно окно и так далее, при этом каждое предыдущее будет висеть в этом состоянии и перекрывать друг друга.

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии следующей кнопки предыдущее popover скрывалось?

**КОД ТАКОЙ:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>popover</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jcart/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jcart/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /> 
<script src="bootstrap/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>  
    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example1').popover({placement:  'right'});
    $('#example2').popover({placement:  'right'});
    $('#example3').popover({placement:  'right'});
    $('#example4').popover({placement:  'right'});
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<a class="btn btn-success btn-small" id="example1" rel="popover" data-content=" Контент" data-original-title="Изменить параметры позиции">Изменить</a><br>
<a class="btn btn-success btn-small" id="example2" rel="popover" data-content=" Контент" data-original-title="Изменить параметры позиции">Изменить</a><br>
<a class="btn btn-success btn-small" id="example3" rel="popover" data-content=" Контент" data-original-title="Изменить параметры позиции">Изменить</a><br>
<a class="btn btn-success btn-small" id="example4" rel="popover" data-content=" Контент" data-original-title="Изменить параметры позиции">Изменить</a>

<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: у вас bootstrap-popover.js подключается 2 раза, не к добру это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFffL/539/), а вообще гугл творит чудеса, [да](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8948587/1221082)

```
$(function() {
    var isVisible = false;

    var hideAllPopovers = function() {
       $('.popup-marker').each(function() {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        });  
    };

    $('.popup-marker').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual'
    }).on('click', function(e) {
        // if any other popovers are visible, hide them
        if(isVisible) {
            hideAllPopovers();
        }

        $(this).popover('show');

        // handle clicking on the popover itself
        $('.popover').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation(); // prevent event for bubbling up => will not get caught with document.onclick
        });

        isVisible = true;
        e.stopPropagation();
    });


    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        hideAllPopovers();
        isVisible = false;
    });
});
```